# How to select a desired training sample from mnist.load_data()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, mnist

New to machine learning here. I am trying to train 1000 pairs of training data and 500 pairs of testing data instead of the whole dataset. However, I am getting the error:

"ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_24 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)"

Here are part of my codes related to the data:

```
# load data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train / 255
X_test = X_test / 255

X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1,28,28) 
X_train = X_train[:1000,:,:]
X_test = X_test[:500,:,:]


y_train = y_train[:1000]
y_test  = y_test[:500]

X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,1,28,28) 

print('X_train shape: ',X_train.shape)
print('X_test shape: ',np.shape(X_test ))
print('y_train shape: ',y_train.shape)
print('y_test shape: ',np.shape(y_test ))
```

output:

X_train shape:  (1000, 1, 28, 28)
X_test shape:  (500, 1, 28, 28)
y_train shape:  (1000,)
y_test shape:  (500,)

Am I doing right on this? Are there any other ways to achieve the goal? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take first 1000 from training set and 500 from test set requires simply just this:

```
X_train = X_train[:1000].reshape(1000,28,28,1)
y_train = y_train[:1000].reshape(1000,1)

X_test = X_test[:500].reshape(500,28,28,1)
y_test = y_test[:500].reshape(500,1)
```

Keras uses channels last by default, hence (batch, 28, 28, 1).
For y, the data needs to be shaped from (batch,) to (batch,1).
You can also take the elements from the first dimension with [:batch] and do the reshaping on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

`X_train` should not be shape (1000, 1, 28, 28).

Using the "channels_last" format of Keras, your data shape should be (Batch x Height x Width x Channel) so (1000,28,28,1).

Check out this example: https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/